# Bootstrap dropdown not visible properly

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I'm having some issues with bootstrap dropdown. I have a container with max-height and inside that number of rows, with each row having an icon, when clicked upon, will show a dropdown. The problem is, when i click on the icon in a row, which is nearly at the bottom of the container, the dropdown shows up, but, behind the container.

Tried setting z-index and position fixed. The problem with position fixed is that when the browser is moved, the dropdown stays where it is. I checked this is safari browser and there it works perfectly. It just scrolls up there to show the entire dropdown. But in other browsers, it doesn't work like that.  Could this be done with CSS only or JS is required ? Thanks

Comment: Can you create a fiddle reproducing the issue?

Comment: Perhaps there's an `overflow: hidden` ?

Comment: @cvrebert No, there is no overflow hidden property